# Can we prove that $\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sin(mx)\sin(ny)|y-x|^{\alpha} \,dx\,dy$ is nonzero?

Tags: real-analysis

### Let $m,n$ be positive integers and $-1<\alpha<0$ be a real number. Can we prove that the integral
$$\int_0^1\int_x^1 \sin(mx)\sin(ny)(y-x)^\alpha \,dy\,dx$$
is nonzero.

There is something wrong with the above question. We change it to
$$\int_0^1\int_0^1 \sin(mx)\sin(ny)|y-x|^{\alpha} \,dx\,dy$$

This is the expected result of random solution in fractional Brownian motion. In the calculation process, it is on the denominator, so I expect it not to be $0$.

Comment: What is the context of this question?  Why do you suspect that the integral cannot be zero?  What have you tried to prove this proposition?

Comment: @MarkViola Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question.  This is a question I asked for my friend.

Comment: I don't think this is true. With $m = 3$, $n = 5$, the integral is equal to $0$ at approximately $\alpha = -0.6631$. Are there any restrictions on $m, n$? It seems to be true for $m > n$ (although I haven't confirmed this).

Comment: @VarunVejalla  I am not sure. This is a question my friend asked,He doesn't have an account with mathstackexchange.
Let me ask him

Comment: @VarunVejalla  Thank you very much for your comment. We have change the question and now m and n are symmetric, and the integral region is also symmetric.